# Wait cursor fires the click event on other click on ribbon button

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto

I have an addin developed in VSTO and as soon as the wait cursor appears 
and if I click on the other button the click event is fired even in the wait cursor.

How can I disable this event click unless the process is completed?

```
public bool Part3DVis_Click(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        xtnvis.HelpNamespace = mobjGlobalConfig.HelpFilenamePath;
        xtnvis.tabConrolVisUpdateHelpKeyword();
        excelComponent.Part3DVis_Click();
        return true;
    }
```

When this event is clicked i need rest of the control n event of other forms to be disable, 
and after it is returned true, it should enable all the events.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = false;
```

set it back to true at the end of your process.

MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.screenupdating.aspx)